# Calculating percentage change with SQL windows analytic function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, analytics, lag

I am working on calculating the percentage change in total scores on a subject over the term using the table below.

```
name  subject  session     term  totalscore
-------------------------------------------
jack  maths    2013/2014    1      70
jack  eng      2013/2014    1      65
jack  science  2013/2014    1      80
jack  maths    2013/2014    2      72
jack  eng      2013/2014    2      87
jack  science  2013/2014    2      67
jack  maths    2013/2014    3      70
jack  eng      2013/2014    3      70
jack  science  2013/2014    3      85
```

I tried using the windows LAG function as seen below to calculate the totalscore percentage change but got NULL values in the percentage_change column

```
SELECT
    name,
    subject,
    term,
    session,
    totalscores -  lag(totalscores, 1) over(partition by subject, session, term order by session, term) / 100*100
FROM
    totalscore
GROUP BY
    name, subject, session, term, totalscores
ORDER BY 
    term
```

The expected result table is meant to look like this

```
name  subject  session     term  totalscore   percent_change
------------------------------------------------------------
jack  maths    2013/2014    1      70           null
jack  eng      2013/2014    1      65           null
jack  science  2013/2014    1      80           null  
jack  maths    2013/2014    2      72           2%
jack  eng      2013/2014    2      87           22%
jack  science  2013/2014    2      67          -5%
jack  maths    2013/2014    3      70          -2%
jack  eng      2013/2014    3      70          -17%
jack  science  2013/2014    3      85           16%
```

Is there any way this can be written to help fix this error? I will appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just want the *difference* (because these are already percents).  But the key is getting the `partition by` correct for the `lag()`:

```
select name, subject, term, session,
       (totalscores -
        lag(totalscores) over(partition by name, subject order by session, term)
       ) as diff
from totalscore
order by name, subject, session, term;
```